# Website can't access files in wwwroot directory on Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, razor

The website works perfectly in Visual Studio, but then I export it using dotnet pusblish and run it, website can't access any files in wwwroot directory. I am on admin account, so no issues there. Moreover, I though, this might be a problem with my project, but even if I created a new one, don't change anything and export it, still the same issue. I am using Windows 10 64-bit.

Edit 1
Tried a different approach and deployed using Visual Studio to iis, but still no luck

Comment: How do you run your website? Are you sure you run It as admin? Which, by the way, does not sound very secure?

Comment: I am running it on a local host from the exe generated by the dotnet publish comand. Tried tu run it as admin, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after hours of trial and error I found a solution. In the _Layout file i had multiple  tags and it only executed one, so after putting everything into the same tag I solved half of the problem. The other problem, which I still don't know what caused, I resolved by not portable and restrictive way, but I had to specific exact location of wwwroot file in a disk using .UseWebRoot(@"C:####\wwwroot").